# Do we need AC to prove Principle of Dependent Choices

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

For any nonempty set $X$ and any entire binary relation $R$ on $X$, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $x_nRx_{n+1}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. (Here an entire binary relation on $X$ is one such that for each $a$ in $X$ there is a $b$ in $X$ such that $aRb$.)

I cant understand why we cant prove DC bu usual induction: let $x_1=x$ for some $x \in X$ and given $x_n$ there exist $y_n$ such that $x_nRy_n$. We set $x_{n+1}=y_n$. It seems that we dont need AC in proving this theorem.

Comment: You need choice: DC is strictly weaker than choice, in that ZF+DC does not prove the axiom of choice, but it is not provable without choice in that it is relatively consistent with ZF that DC fails.

Comment: As for your specific question: You say: Given $x_n$, there exists $y_n$ such that $x_n\mathrel{R}y_n$. However, it is a bit misleading to talk of $y_n$, as this makes it appear as if it is unique. The problem is that there may be many sets $y$ with $x_n\mathrel{R} y$, and you need to choose one of them as your $x_{n+1}$. You need to do this infinitely many times, so definitely some form of choice is required in this argument. If choice is not to be used, you need to specify how, precisely, $x_{n+1}$ is being selected from all the candidates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't just prove $\sf DC$ is that you are making infinitely many choices at once. There is, generally, no well-defined mechanism for choosing the specific $x_{n+1}$.

In some cases you can in fact prove that such sequence exist, but those are the exception, not the general rule.

As Andres notes in the comments, $\sf DC$ is vastly weaker than $\sf AC$ itself, although it is quite sufficient for many classical results which need the axiom of choice. Perhaps I should add that your confusion on the topic is exactly why this is such a natural choice principle, and that many people who argued against the axiom of choice were actually using it without knowing.